# Meaning of "you…calculate about your next victim and reckon on your chances of recompense…" and "why should I take only what no one else wants?"

Tags: meaning

In the following quotes from "The Stronger" by August Strindberg, what does "you sit here and calculate about
your next victim and reckon on your chances of recompense like a pilot
in a shipwreck" and "why should I take only what no one else wants?" mean?

> You couldn't scent your prey and capture it, but you could lie in wait
> for it! You sit here in your corner of the cafe--did you know it's
> called "The Rat Trap" for you?--and read the papers to see if
> misfortune hasn't befallen some one, to see if some one hasn't been
> given notice at the theatre, perhaps; **you sit here and calculate about
> your next victim and reckon on your chances of recompense like a pilot
> in a shipwreck.** Poor Amelie, I pity you, nevertheless, because I know
> you are unhappy, unhappy like one who has been wounded, and angry
> because you are wounded. I can't be angry with you, no matter how much
> I want to be--because you come out the weaker one.
>
> Well, judging by certain signs, I believe you have already lost him;
> and you certainly intended that I should leave him--do as you did with
> your fiancé and regret as you now regret; but, you see, I don't do
> that--we mustn't be too exacting. And **why should I take only what no
> one else wants?**

Here is the text from other translations:

- 1a)Here you watch your victims and calculate your chances and take your tributes.
- 1b)And why should I take only what nobody else wants?
- 2a)here you sit and review your work, calculating your mischief as a pilot does his course; collecting your tribute
- 2b)And why should I take only what nobody else will have?

Comment: Do you realise that Strindberg wrote in Swedish, so this is a translation? Surely the meaning of the second extract is plain enough.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes I know. I've read three different translations.

Comment: Then you should have mentioned it in your question. How do the three translations compare?

Comment: @KateBunting Other translations: 1a)Here you watch your victims and calculate your chances and take your tributes. 1b)And why should I take only what nobody else wants? 2a)here you sit and review your work, calculating your mischief as a pilot does his course; collecting your tribute 2b)And why should I take only what nobody else will have?

Comment: The literal meaning and grammar of "reckon on your chances of recompense like a pilot in a shipwreck" is plain, but it needs some explanation of the situation it is imagining (what a pilot is, and how they might have been involved in a shipwreck). You should do some research and try to work this out.

Comment: The second quote means exactly what it says: If he's not good enough for other people, why should she take him as a boyfriend?

Comment: @Barmar But He's her husband and she says she won't leave him. It doesn't make sense saying such thing. Thoughts?

Comment: @tommy859 Sorry, I didn't notice the context. Is the other person suggesting she leave her husband in favor of someone else? It seems like "what no one else wants" must refer to something that has already been established.

Comment: @Barmar She's talking to a girl that she thinks her husband had an affair with.  She thinks the girl wanted her to leave her husband but she says she won't do that.

Comment: I get it. If the other woman wants him, he must be desirable. The only way to get a man with no competition is for him to be someone no one else wants, and that's clearly an undesirable man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second quote expresses the idea that her husband is desirable, so other women are naturally going to be attracted to him. She's not going to leave him because the other woman is trying to steal him away from her. The only way to avoid that is to marry someone no one else would want, but that means he would be an undesirable husband, and why should she settle for that?

Comment: Many many thanks. Any idea about the first quote?

Comment: Nope. That's why SE questions should be focused on a single question, so you don't run into the problem of separate answers to each question.